# ¿Porq qué recibo este error? "PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined"

Tags: php, sql, cms

Tengo un problema

```
if(isset($_SESSION['admin'])){
    require '../resources/php/funciones.php';
    $obj = new Funciones();
    if(isset($_POST['titulo'], $_POST['contenido'] )){
        $subir = $obj->subirServicio($_POST['titulo'], $_POST['contenido'], $_SESSION['admin']);
        if($subir == true){
            echo '<span class="alert alert-succes">El servicio ha sido subido</span>';
        }
    }
```

**Esta es la función que da el problema, en la linea que dice :** `infor_serv => $contenido`

```
       public function subirServicio($titulo, $contenido){
            global $pdo;

            $query = $pdo->prepare("
            INSERT INTO servicios (nombre_serv, info_serv)
            VALUES(:titulo, :contenido)
             ");

            $query-> execute ([
                'nombre_serv' => $titulo,
                'info_serv' => $contenido
            ]);

            if ($query){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Están mal los nombres de los parametros, los correctos son :titulo y :contenido, no mobre_serv e info_serv

Comment: Recuerda que si te sirvió la respuesta, vota como respuesta correcta para ayudar a los demás usuarios que puedan tener el mismo problema

Answer (score 3):

Viendo los marcadores de *nombres* o como lo especifica la documentación *marcadores de parámetros con nombre* (gracias a @shadow por la corrección) que usas para tu consulta (:titulo y :contenido), de esa misma forma se deben llamar las llaves que pasas dentro del diccionaro del execute, te recomiendo que mantengas los mismos nombres para todo, asi evitas errores de escritura.

```
public function subirServicio($nombre_serv, $info_serv){
            global $pdo;

            $query = $pdo->prepare("
            INSERT INTO servicios (nombre_serv, info_serv)
            VALUES(:nombre_serv, :info_serv)
             ");

            $query-> execute ([
                'nombre_serv' => $nombre_serv,
                'info_serv' => $info_serv
            ]);

            if ($query){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
```

De esta forma, deberia funcionar. Si cuando obtienes esos valores usas titulo y contenido como nombres de variable, no importara para los argumentos de la función.

Comment: solo una observación, en este caso se les conoce como marcadores de nombre por tener la sintáxis de `:nombre`